# Is it possible to insert unity3d player on wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, unity-game-engine

How do I insert unity3d player on WordPress page?

There is no option for it in insert media library by default. I tried UnityDog plugin but it does not work. It enables unity file type in media upload, however uploaded files are removed for security reasons.

If I want to make a plugin for it where do I start? Is it very complex? I am new to WordPress.

Comment: upload it somewhere else and paste the embedded code in your blog

Comment: How do i insert html code directly? There have to be script tag inserted and player div tag inserted.

Comment: your game's embeded code is regular HTML code. Try googling "adding HTML to wordpress post"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a basic knowledge of PHP, you can create your own plugin and use Wordpress' shortcode to display your html & javascript wherever the shortcode is called in the site.

Registering a short code is easy:

```
function unity3dPlayer(){
    ?>
    <div>This is where your HTML & Javascript should go.</div> 
    <?php
}

add_shortcode(‘UnityPlayerShortCode’, ‘unity3dPlayer’);
```

You can also put the above code in your theme's functions.php file. When you want to show your player, simply use `[UnityPlayerShortCode]` in the body of the post / page.

Here's a useful tutorial for you to follow if you'd like to create a plugin:

https://www.inkthemes.com/learn-how-to-create-shortcodes-in-wordpress-plugin-with-examples/

Comment: There are two errors in your shortcode. You should not to use echo but return the content of the shortcode to get proper placement of result and function name and shortcode name should be in lowercase.